# Why is my <root-device> mounted to /var/lib/docker/plugins

Tags: linux, docker

Why is my systems root device (`/dev/mapper/system-root` in my case) mounted to `/var/lib/docker/plugins`?

By default this device is already mounted to `/`. After I installed docker, I noticed that now this same device is also mounted to `/var/lib/docker/plugins`

I'm using docker-ce on an ubuntu (artful) system.

Comment: Well it is probably a bind mount, not mounted twice.  I don't know docker well, but I assume it is bind mounted because something needs it to be, or was configured for that to happen.

Comment: Probably a bind mount. Look at the mount options.

Comment: yes. you're correct.. I also asked a question on github.. and got a details response.. see [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/260)